# How to use loop within a loop in salesforce flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

Requirement: A note will be created for a selected account from the list view, using a custom button. This button calls a VFPage & that vfpage calls this flow.
My current output creates the correct number of notes but with multiple accounts associated with each note but I only want single account to be associated with each note. Need help or suggestions

Idea is to assign each ContentDocumentLink record to each unique ContentNote & unique AccountID

[image]

1. looping over Account IDs
2. looping over ContentNote (adding ContentDocumentLink records in collection inside this loop)

[image: loop_within_the_loop_insf_flow]

Comment: What's your actual question? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @sfdcfox , so I am creating automated notes using a custom button on account object for the selected accounts by a vfp which calls this flow & in this loop I am trying to create ContentDocumentLink(CDL) records with assigning each account to CDL's LinkedEntityID, as to create and link a note to account I need a CDL record and it is requires AccID and ContentDocumentID(Im passing ContentNote Id here, which I created earlier in the flow) . But output creates no. of notes with all accIds, same as no. of accounts I selected, that's is fine but I need only one account to associate to each note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the answer, below screenshot is the logic I implemented.

[image]